# Sliding tile puzzle in Python 3, where to begin?

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, a-star, heuristics, sliding-tile-puzzle

I am pretty new to coding and I'm currently stuck on the following practice questions in my textbook.

1. Write a program that generates an 'eight puzzle'. It should randomly shuffle the puzzle, then allow the user to solve it.
2. Extend your program so it has a 'solve' option that will solve it using A* search.

The problem is, after hours of browsing the web and YouTube, I only come across tutorials and examples which either assume advanced knowledge of this topic or include no useful annotations which would help me learn it.

I was wondering if anyone could please point me to a resource of some sort that explains how to even approach such a puzzle in Python 3. I have no clue what the best way to learn and start this is.

Thank you in advance for your time and help.

Comment: I assume you know what a graph is, since you tagged this with 'A\*'. If so, what are some ways you could represent this problem as a graph?

Comment: Using `A *`, I assume you could solve the problem using `bfs`, and so you know that `A*` gives a better performance by using a heuristic function (depend on the problem you have), for a weighted graph (weight not equal one everywhere), we are using those weights for our heuristic function, therefore, I assume you have a problem with choosing the heuristic function, you can use `Manhattan distance`, and choose the path which minimizes the distance function.

Comment: I appreciate the answers, but I meant more of a coding side of things rather than the general concept of what is going on. I simply do not know what kind of classes and methods my code should include and how the entire program should be structured. This is all new to me so I'm searching for a decent tutorial on writing a sliding-block puzzle.

Comment: Start by modeling. That is what programming is about: building a model for a problem. First step you need to model a puzzle, right ? Here is something to get you started:  have a class that represents a puzzle. The actual representation in the class can be a 3x3 array for example. Second step:  you need to be able to generate a random puzzle.   Third step: move from one puzzle state to the next (by sliding one tile).